# Search controls in a flowlayoutpanel c#

Tags: c#, search, foreach, flowlayoutpanel

[image]

I'm trying to create a selection for roomType but why some controls are showing even its not equal on Combobox text here is my code in Combobox

```
private void cbRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    GenerateDynamicUserControl(); 
    foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) 
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(CustomerControl)) 
        {
            CustomerControl customerControl = (CustomerControl)c; 
            if (!customerControl.RoomType.ToLower().Contains(cbRoomType.Text.ToLower())) 
            {
                 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(c);                 
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Im expecting to solve my problem

Comment: i am guessing that stepping through with a debugger will tell you in 30 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You are committing the cardinal sin of modifying the collection while iterating over it with a `foreach`.

Add all your matches to a separate list and then remove them afterwards:

```
private void cbRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    GenerateDynamicUserControl(); 
    List<CustomerControl> matches = new List<CustomerControl>();
    foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) 
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(CustomerControl)) 
        {
            CustomerControl customerControl = (CustomerControl)c; 
            if (!customerControl.RoomType.ToLower().Contains(cbRoomType.Text.ToLower())) 
            {
                 matches.Add(c);                     
            }
        }
     }
     foreach(var c in matches) {
         flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(c); 
     }                
 }
```